# Small assembly code sequence optimization (intel x86)

Tags: optimization, assembly, x86, intel

I am doing some exercises in assembly language and I found a question about optimization which I can't figure out. Can anyone help me with them

So the question is to optimize the following assembly code:

----------------------------Example1-------------------------

```
mov dx, 0 ---> this one I know-> xor dx,dx
```

----------------------------Example2------------------------

```
cmp ax, 0
je label
```

----------------------------Example3-------------------------

```
mov ax, x
cwd
mov si, 16  
idiv si
```

----> Most I can think of in this example is to subs last 2 lines by idiv 16, but I am not sure

----------------------------Example4-------------------------

```
mov ax, x
mov bx, 7
mul bx
mov t, ax
```

----------------------------Example5---------------------------

```
mov si, offset array1
mov di, offset array2
; for i = 0; i < n; ++i
do:
   mov bx, [si]
   mov [di], bx
   add si, 2
   add di, 2
loop do
endforloop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example 2, you should look at the `and` or `test` opcodes. Similar to example 1, they allow you to remove the need for a constant.

For example 4, remember that `x * 7` is the same as `x * (8 - 1)` or, expanding that, `x * 8 - x`. Multiplying by eight can be done with a shift instruction.

For example 5, you'd think Intel would have provided a much simpler way to transfer from SI to DI, since that is the whole reason for their existence. Maybe something like a REPetitive MOVe String Word :-)

Answer (score 0):

For example three, division by a power of two can be implemented as a right shift.

Note that in example 5, the current code fails to initialize CX as needed (and in the optimized version, you'd definitely want to do that too).

Comment: Common misconception. `idiv` works on signed integers and.. well `-3/2 != -3 >> 1`.

Comment: @Voo: You need to look a little more carefully at the x86 instruction set, particularly the fact that it has both `shr` (logical shift right) and `sar` (arithmetic shift right). `sar` produces arithmetically correct results for dividing either positive or negative numbers by powers of 2.

Comment: No you're missing the point. It's not that the sign bit isn't extended. There are basically 3 different modes of division (truncating, modulus, floor). And the sign extending right shift trick only works for the modulus and floor definitions. Now the problem is that C and co all demand truncating division and well - it doesn't work there. Hence `-3/2 == -1` while `-3 >> 1 == -2`. (can be fixed with 2 additional instructions though and is usually still far more efficient)

Comment: @Voo: Who said anything about producing the same result as C (or any other high level language)?

Comment: Well the original code uses `idiv`, `idiv` does truncating division (not that surprising, although I'm not sure whether x86 or c was first) and the goal is to optimize the code which generally includes not changing the result?

Comment: @Voo: that depends -- in many (most?) cases people are willing to allow minor differences if they get enough improvement elsewhere to justify it -- particularly when the difference is something like rounding up vs. down, and the original choice was mostly arbitrary anyway. Before C99, C allowed either -1 or -2 in this case, as long as `%` produced a result that matched.

Comment: Returning a **wrong** result for 50% of all numbers isn't a minor difference, but just plain wrong. Yes c89 didn't specify it, so it was fine back then (but only if we also did modulus/floor division for all positive numbers as well). I think the vast majority of people will agree that an optimizing compiler may not change the result of a spec confirming program (except if the spec makes a special exception for it, which isn't true here). There are still optimizations we can do even for truncating division, it's just 2/3 cheap instructions more - hardly a problem.

Comment: @Voo: On what basis do you decide that truncating is "right" and rounding toward zero is "**wrong**"? Sorry, but it's pretty clear that even you realize you're wrong on this one, and you're just yelling to try to keep from admitting to the obvious.

Comment: I decide that truncating division is right, because idiv does so and that's the unoptimized original. If you really think that it's fine to return an off-by-one result of the actual code, you're in the vast minority: Not a single compiler I know of (gcc, MSVCC, hotspot,..) does that optimization without the fixup, for *obvious* reasons. Heck they don't even reorder fp math by default because that would change the result minimally as well. Why not replace the idiv call with `xor eax, eax`? That result is also only off by a constant :)